# Get the latest value for a cell in a series of rows that share a unique identifier in Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a unique issue, I have a file full of data. THis data is then summed together using Pandas in cases where rows have the same ID. The data in each row is varied but most of the Strings in the row are static and the integers in the file are added together using Pandas:

```
aframe.columns = ['ID','blah2', 'blah3', 'integer1'.......]

aframe['integer1'] = aframe['integer1'].convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')
aframe['integer2'] = aframe['integer2'].convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')
aframe['integer3'] = aframe['integer3'].convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')
aframe['integer4'] = aframe['integer4'].convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')

aframe = aframe.groupby(['ID', 'blah1', 'blah2',......])

aframe.to_csv(outputFile)
```

However, I recently learned that one value in particular has to be set to the latest value when summed together, in other words the value of the last row that shares the same ID. Is there a Pandas way of going about this without doing file parsing acrobatics?

**UPDATE:**
So, as an example of the table, its' in the format of:

```
ID Blah2 Blah3 Integer1 ....
A   On    Name   34
B   Off   Name2  76
A   Off   Name   34
B   On    Name2  23
```

I want it summed together like such, with the last value of Blah2 being the value of that cell in the summed row:

```
ID Blah2 Blah3 Integer1 ....
A   Off    Name   68
B   On     Name2  99
```

Comment: do you mean `aframe.last()`?

Comment: Do you have an example usage of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby('ID')` followed by `aggregate` with specified function per column:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', 'On', 34],
        ['B', 'Off', 76],
        ['A', 'Off', 34],
        ['B', 'On', 23]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('ID', 'Blah', 'Integer'), data=data)
df
>>>     ID  Blah    Integer
>>> 0   A   On      34
>>> 1   B   Off     76
>>> 2   A   Off     34
>>> 3   B   On      23

df.groupby('ID').aggregate({'Blah': 'last', 'Integer': 'mean'})
>>>     Blah    Integer
>>> ID      
>>> A   Off     34.0
>>> B   On      49.5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks very much.